# ASP.NET CORE with React Publish

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created a ASP.NET Core app with React as per the tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022

When I try to publish the app, it creates in my project folder under obj\Release\net7.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\ a copy of every single file on the entire drive where my project lies. And then I get errors that the files paths are too long because it is trying to copy stuff that is in the recycle bin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG29d.png)

Is there another way to publish this? Easy to publish the backEnd web API app, but how do I publish the FrontEnd

Comment: Well, for publishing `react app` which combined with asp.net core you should follow few additional steps. Please check the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022#publish-the-project)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes that is the steps I folloed, but then it dumps everything under the drive root into the PubTmp folder

Comment: It should allow you to choose your own folder to publish therefore, it shouldn't dump automeetically any folder. Are you getting any error?

Comment: The errors I am getting is when the publisher wants to copy the files from the PubTMP folder to publish folder and the errors are all that the file names are too long because everyuthing from my recycleBin has also been copied into the PubTMP folder

Comment: Yes when the path become too long you would get such issue. Why your path too long? Why don't you publish your app in shorter path folder?

Comment: My path is short. The long paths comes from the fact that is is trying to copy things it shouldn't

Comment: Did you tried manually to do that in other folder? Or do you have any other machine to check the publish process?